How to relate two tables in Apache Superset so that filtering one field affects the entire table?
I'm working on a project in Apache Superset and I'm having difficulties relating two tables in a way that filtering one field affects the entire table. Here's my situation:

Tables Involved:


I have two main tables, let's say "Orders" and "Customers".

The "Orders" table contains information about each order, including the customer ID associated with each order.

The "Customers" table contains details about each customer, including the customer ID.



Objective:


My goal is to create a relationship between these two tables in such a way that when filtering a customer in the "Customers" table, the orders related to that customer are displayed in the "Orders" table. In other words, I would like filtering a field in the "Customers" table to affect the entire "Orders" table.


Problem:


So far, I haven't been able to set up this relationship effectively in Apache Superset. When I filter a customer in the "Customers" table, only the orders for that specific customer are displayed in the "Orders" table, instead of displaying all orders related to that customer.


Actions Taken:


I've tried configuring the joins between the tables in the dataset settings, but I haven't been able to achieve the desired result.

I've also tried creating a custom SQL view to join the tables and then saving that query as a new dataset, but I still haven't had success.


Could someone please guide me on how to properly set up this relationship in Apache Superset? I'm open to suggestions for alternative approaches or any other solution that can solve this problem. Thank you in advance for your help!
